# Ошибка при запуске DialogFragment

Tags: android

У меня есть `DialogFragment`:

```
public class WorkWithDictionaries extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    public WorkWithDictionaries(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, Context context) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        editText_1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_1);
        editText_1.setText("TEXT");

        Button dialogBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    }

}
```

При его вызове, через `.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragment") выскакивает ошибка:

```
11-21 17:30:25.637    2888-2888/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:229)
            at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Dialog.java:1035)
            at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Скорее всего убирание вот этой строчки должно убрать ошибку : setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, помогло, но получилась та еще фигня... Добавьте в ответ.

Comment: Проверьте сначала не поможет ли вызов этого до super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), а не после

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не помогло... А можно `Dialog` или `AlertDialog` вызвать без `ActionBar`?